# Custom renderer class doesn’t applies on logs

Tags: c#, nlog

I have two targets in my nlog.config file

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="File"
      name="logfile"
      fileName="../../../Log/log.log">
    <layout xsi:type="Layout">
      <renderer type="truncate" maxMessageLength="500" />
    </layout>
  </target>

  <target xsi:type="Console"
      name="logconsole"      
      layout="${truncate:MaxLength=20}">
  </target>
</targets>
```

None of them works, because of custom renderer class, but all code I wrote based on manuals and chatgpt.

Here is my class

```
[LayoutRenderer("truncate")]
public class TruncateLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    [RequiredParameter]
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        string formattedLogEntry = $"test {logEvent.TimeStamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {logEvent.Level:uppercase=true} - {logEvent.FormattedMessage}";

        if (formattedLogEntry.Length > MaxLength)
        {
            formattedLogEntry = formattedLogEntry.Substring(0, MaxLength);
        }

        builder.Append(formattedLogEntry);
    }
}
```

Config file and class in in one project

When I launch project I see that layout is set on default. But if I use layout hardcoded in config file it works. What is wrong with my class?

I read manuals and asked gpt, it seems that everything is coorect

Comment: Exciting how you are just glueing random stuff together and posting it as question. If you read the wiki-page [How to write a custom layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer#class), then it says [Don't forget to register your custom component](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component)

Comment: Notice there already exists a built-in truncate method in NLog. So you can just do this `${message:truncate=500}` (without needing custom layout renderer). See also https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the wiki-page [How to write a custom layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer#class), then it says [Don't forget to register your custom component](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component)

But notice there already exist a built-in truncate-method in NLog. So you can just do this `${message:truncate=500}` (without needing your own custom layout renderer.

See also: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers